# Azure DataCache MaxConnectionToServer

Tags: azure, appfabric

I am using the AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider and occasionally get the error

> ErrorCode:SubStatus:There is a temporary failure. Please retry later.
>   (The request failed, because you exceeded quota limits for this hour.
>   If you experience this often, upgrade your subscription to a higher
>   one). Additional Information : Throttling due to resource :
>   Connections.

I am using a basic 128mb cache with a web role which has two instances. What is the default MaxConnectionToServer value if it is not set? I think when I fire up a staging instance as well it can cause this error (4 simultaneous instances). Will setting MaxConnectionToServer to a higher value make it better or worse? I believe the 128mb cache has limit of 5 connections so should I set it to 1 which would mean only 4 connections could be used. The cache is not used elsewhere in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [default for MaxConnectToServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790816.aspx) is 1, so you shouldn't have to change this setting, but if you do set it to 1, it will avoid anyone else looking at your config from getting confused as well.  If you set it to a higher value then you will see this problem more often.

The cache session provider seems to be a little slow at disposing of its connections to the cache when it doesn't need them any more.  This means that if you're running a number of instances which is close to the limit for you cache size you do seem to see this error.  You're correct a 128MB cache does only [allow 5 concurrent connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602420.aspx#CACHING_FAQ).  If you want to avoid this problem at the moment the only solution I'm aware of is to buy the next cache size up.

Comment: Thanks. I have 4 instances (two prod, two staging) so this could be causing this issue occasionally. I am looking at getting rid of sessions altogether to eliminate the need for the cache.